# What is another way to say "it refers to something"

Tags: word-choice

I've created a question using "beziehen sich auf etw." but all my questions became the same. I would like to ask the same question but using different words.

> Welcher der folgenden Termini bezieht sich auf die zwei Sorten eines Sprachsystems, welche gegenseitig verständlich sind?
>
> A) X
>
> B) Y(suppose that this is true)

How could I in the question above "bezieht sich" omit and use another verb instead?

Here it is original question:

[image]

Comment: Huh? "Der folgenden *what? Antworten?* bezieht sich ..., *and then it gets very confusing*".  Could you check especially the part after the comma, please?

Comment: der folgenden Kaffee :D, it is a question and a question may have only answers, I just tried to say "which of the following". The part after comma is: [...]die zwei Sorten eines Sprachsystems, die[...], so I didn't understand what's wrong with it,because relative part describes "die zwei Sorten". I've edited the question I hope, it is clearer now

Comment: Das fällt mir spontan ein.
"Bei welchem der beiden Begriffe handelt es sich um ..."
"Welcher Begriff beschreibt ..."

Comment: @MurVotema I thought that "beiden" refers to two things only, am I wrong?

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I think `Welches der folgenden Termini` should be `Welcher folgenden der Termini`, because `der Terminus` is masculine.

Comment: @raznagul you're right, I'll edit it not to confuse the others

Comment: From my personal experience I can confirm that dialects are **not** necessarily mutually intelligible.

Comment: @Jan maybe you experienced german dialect, have you considered about Russian between weiss russia and russian, Turkish(in Turkey) - Turkish(in azerbaijan) these languages are mutually intelligible though. I've heard when in germany in Ruhr area from a friend of me that he said: "I don't even understand bayerisch."

Comment: Could also be translated als *bezeichnen* (*Welcher der folgenden Termini bezeichnet...* or *Mit welchem der folgenden Termini bezeichnet man...*).

Answer (score 2):

Proposal:

> Welcher der folgenden Begriffe bezeichnet die beiden [passenden Fachbegriff für Varianten einsetzen] jedes linguistischen Systems, die wechselweise/gegenseitig verständlich sind? [...]

*Refers to* is not intended to establish a reference here, but is a simple query, which of the terms is counterpart of the specified meaning.

Comment: If I rephrase the like this makes it sense [...]bezeichnet die beiden Varienten jedes linguistischen Systems,die [...] ?

Comment: @Dragut Unfortunately I don't understand your last comment. I'm also still unsure, whether one of the answers has to be chosen (which then represents two variants) or whether two answers are expected, each corresponding to one variant.

Comment: Aha I understand what causes you confusing,no no only one answer is expected to choose, I'll edit my question again

Answer (score 0):

In this case both "referenzieren" and "referieren" are okay.

They both mean "etwas in Beziehung zu etwas anderem setzen" or "auf etwas zu verweisen".
I'd prefer "referieren", because it's a valid and often used term in german linguistic science.

A correct sentence would be:

> Welcher der folgenden Termini referiert/referenziert auf die zwei Sorten eines Sprachsystems, welche gegenseitig verständlich sind?

For referenzieren see: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/referenzieren
and for "referieren" see: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/referieren#Bedeutung2

Another option you might see sometimes would be to use the word "verweisen".

> Welcher der folgenden Termini verweist auf die zwei Sorten eines Sprachsystems, welche gegenseitig verständlich sind.

Another possibility would be "auf etwas Bezug nehmen". I know it sounds a lot like "sich auf etwas beziehen", but it's not the same thing. Both are valid expressions. German also sometimes allows you to change the structure of the sentence, this way you get two possible ways of phrasing your question:

> Welcher der folgenden Termini nimmt Bezug auf die zwei Sorten eines Sprachsystems, welche gegenseitig verständlich sind?

or

> Welcher der folgenden Termini nimmt auf die zwei Sorten eines Sprachsystems Bezug, welche gegenseitig verständlich sind?

Comment: Deine Fprmulierungen sind OK, aber jetzt sollte man an den "zwei Sorten" arbeiten - für ein Sprachsystem hört sich das dämlich an, wie im Kramladen.

Comment: Ich verstehe was du meinst, aber das ist zu umfassend um das hier zu erklären.
Im Prinzip ist es möglich Sätze umzustellen, auf Basis trennbarer zusammengesetzter Verben.
"Auf Etwas Bezug nehmen" ist jedoch kein Verb im klassischen Sinne (wie zum Beispiel "abheben" oder "weglaufen") sondern ein Ausdruck.  Das einzige, was dieser Ausdruck noch mit dem Verb "beziehen" gemein hat ist, dass es eine Substantivierung von "beziehen" ist (beziehen -> der Bezug).
Die Erklärung der deutschen Syntaxregeln wäre in dem Fall schon eher ihren eigenen Post wert und viel zu umfassend für diese Frage hier.